# Change Foreign Key Value in Access Query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

Here is a small example of what I would like to accomplish.

Table 1: Person

- ID
- FirstName
- HairColor_ID

Table 2: HairColor

- ID
- Color

I have Query 1 where I give it a color parameter(c) and it returns the ID of that Hair Color

```
SELECT HairColor.ID
FROM HairColor
WHERE (([HairColor].[Color]=[c]));
```

Now in Query 2, I have the Person table and the Query 1. In the field, I want to choose ID 2 of person and change its HairColor_ID according to the Query 1 result(which should return an ID), Query 2 is below:

```
UPDATE Person INNER JOIN Query1 ON Person.ID = Query1.ID SET 
Person.HairColor_ID = [Query1]![ID]
WHERE (((Person.ID)=2));
```

I would assume [Query1]![ID] returns the ID.

Basically all I want to do is update the HairColor_ID by giving the Color Value as a parameter. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what you want is to update a `CROSS JOIN` between `Person` and `HairColor`.  You don't need `Query1`, and to me at least the mechanism is clearer without it.

```
PARAMETERS c Text ( 255 );
UPDATE Person, HairColor
SET Person.HairColor_ID = [HairColor].[ID]
WHERE Person.id=2 AND HairColor.Color=[c];
```

Comment: This is what I actually was trying to go for but couldn't figure it out without having another query. Thank you.

Comment: With your SQL and mine, the GUI displayed the exact same thing except that my GUI showed the relation between the 2, so when I removed that it fixed it. I just thought that was weird.

Comment: Yeah, you gotta be skeptical about those Design View relations.  It may allow you to join tables on arbitrary numeric fields ... say `Person_ID` and `Engine_Displacement` ... but that doesn't mean it's a useful or meaningful join.   Yours amounted to `ON Person.ID = HairColor.ID`, although `Query1` kind of obscured that fact.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to join the Person table with Query1 via Person.ID = Query1.ID but Query1.ID isn't the ID of a person but of a haircolor...

This query should change the HairColor of person 2 to the color you enter as the parameter c:

```
UPDATE Person, Query1 SET Person.HairColor_ID = [Query1].[ID]
WHERE (((Person.ID)=2));
```

Comment: This is basically what I asked for. Thank you for your response. HansUp provided an answer that is what I originally attempted to do but couldn't find how to do it which led me to creating a 2nd query. Again I appreciate it!